# Does nghttp2 run on FreeRTOS?

Tags: http, http2, freertos

I am looking for http2 client library/code that runs on FreeRTOS

It looks to me that nghttp2 runs on Linux, but then from [here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/61036/embedded-client-using-mbedtls-nghttp2-connection-r.html), that someone is runing the nghttp2 on the FreeRTOS. This doesn't make any sense to me. Do you guys have any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum packet size requirement for HTTP2 can make it hard to run an HTTP2 client on the MCUs normally used with [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org).  Are you sure you have enough memory?

Comment: Dear Richard, how much memory do I normally need?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum max window size defined in HTTP/2 is 16384 which means you need at least 16K bytes memory. HPACK also require code size for huffman table. As my observation the huffman table has size around 10K bytes.